# Sharing JavaScript between multiple Lightning Components

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller

In a Lightning Component we have the notion of a JavaScript controller and a [helper](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_helper.htm). We can use the helper to call code from the JavaScript  controller that is shared between functions, so we can reduce redundancy in the code. This all works great.

However, I was wondering if it is possible, and if so how, to share code between multiple Lightning Components. It doesn't behave like Apex where you can just reference other class.

I was looking at [inheritance and abstract components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_whats_inherited.htm), but I was thinking of code that is shared between components that aren't necessarily related to each other, such as code to handle object and field-level errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently the recommended mechanism for this is to use a Static Resource and include it in any components that need to share the same JavaScript via ltng:require (loads the library once and only once similar to requirejs).

Answer (score 4):

I'm bringing up this old post in case anyone searches for this. I've created a Service Component pattern. It's working great for one of my production projects, but it still has plenty of room for improvement.

The Service Component pattern has more re-usability and is more akin to having one place to reference an Apex Controller.

https://github.com/tsalb/sfdc-lightning-service-components